# What happened to the humans in Ice Age?

Tags: plot-explanation, ice-age

What happened to the humans in *Ice Age* films? The humans don't appear after the first film, (not including the Xmas special.)

Comment: Do you mean the specific tribe from the first film, or humanity in general?

Comment: @F1Krazy sound like in general

Comment: Considering all the scientific impossibilities in the Ice Age series of movies, the herd simply not happening to meet any more humans doesn't seem very odd or the first question I would have.

Comment: In general, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humans were pretty rare animals at the time. At different periods during the ice age there were between 10,000 and one million humans on the entire planet. So it would not have been impossible for animals to rarely encounter them.